# Sneaky way of disabling a button once it's been pressed?

Tags: python, button, lambda, tkinter

Here's the catch, the button has no name!

Code:

```
  Button(buttonFrame, height=2, width=5, text = alpha[i], command=lambda j=i:
  self.letterGuess(alpha[j])).grid(row=1, column=self.columnz(i))
```

I've created a loop within a Tkinter class that creates 26 letter buttons. For now, when the button is pressed, a callback function (`letterGuess`) is executed and the command line prints out "Button `%s`" `%` letter".

But I'd also like to disable the button upon pressing it. How may one go about doing so?

Edit:
Here's the loop:

```
    alpha = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    buttonFrame = Frame(self).grid(row=0, column=1)
    for i in range(len(alpha)):

        if i <= 6:
             Button(buttonFrame, height=2, width=5, text = alpha[i], command=lambda j=i: self.letterGuess(alpha[j])).grid(row=1, column=self.columnz(i))
        elif i > 6 and i <=13:
            Button(buttonFrame, height=2, width=5, text = alpha[i], command=lambda j=i: self.letterGuess(alpha[j])).grid(row=2, column=self.columnz(i))
        elif i > 13 and i <=20:
            Button(buttonFrame, height=2, width=5, text = alpha[i], command=lambda j=i: self.letterGuess(alpha[j])).grid(row=3, column=self.columnz(i))
        elif i > 20 and i <26:
            Button(buttonFrame, height=2, width=5, text = alpha[i], command=lambda j=i: self.letterGuess(alpha[j])).grid(row=4, column=self.columnz(i))
```

Comment: Show loop how you create buttons.

Comment: Check out the Button-attribute *state* and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need button reference - so you need to assign `Button` to variable

```
temp = Button(...)
temp.config(command=lambda j=i, button=temp: self.letterGuess(alpha[j], button))
temp.grid(...)
```

Now you get reference to this button in `letterGuess` and you can use it to disable button

```
def letterGuess(letter, button):
    button.config(state=DISABLED)
```

But if you need to change button state later you could save reference in list or dictionary

```
# before loop
all_buttons = dict()

# inside loop
all_buttons[ alpha[i] ] = Button(...)
all_buttons[ alpha[i] ].grid(...) 

# in function
def letterGuess(letter):
    all_buttons[ letter ].config(state=DISABLED)
```

**EDIT:**

```
alpha = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
buttonFrame = Frame(self).grid(row=0, column=1)

all_buttons = dict()

for i in range(len(alpha)):

    if i <= 6:
         all_buttons[ alpha[i] ] = Button(buttonFrame, height=2, width=5, text = alpha[i], command=lambda j=i: self.letterGuess(alpha[j]))
         all_buttons[ alpha[i] ].grid(row=1, column=self.columnz(i))
    elif 6 < i <=13:
         all_buttons[ alpha[i] ] = Button(buttonFrame, height=2, width=5, text = alpha[i], command=lambda j=i: self.letterGuess(alpha[j]))
         all_buttons[ alpha[i] ].grid(row=2, column=self.columnz(i))
    elif 13 < i <=20:
         all_buttons[ alpha[i] ] = Button(buttonFrame, height=2, width=5, text = alpha[i], command=lambda j=i: self.letterGuess(alpha[j]))
         all_buttons[ alpha[i] ].grid(row=3, column=self.columnz(i))
    elif 20 < i <26:
         all_buttons[ alpha[i] ] = Button(buttonFrame, height=2, width=5, text = alpha[i], command=lambda j=i: self.letterGuess(alpha[j]))
         all_buttons[ alpha[i] ].grid(row=4, column=self.columnz(i))
```

---

**BTW:**

You can use `6 < i <=13` in place of `i > 6 and i <= 13`

You can use

```
for i, letter in enumerate(alpha):
```

and then you can use `letter` in place of `alpha[i]`

Comment: I thought of assigning button to variable, but then I'd have to create 26 button variables, correct? Is there no way to use a loop for that?

Comment: You can use list or dictionary to keep references to button. And you can do it in loop like in answer.

Comment: Nice. I will give this a try momentarily. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I add example with your loop.